# Azure Service Plan is displayed empty and cannot be deleted

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-service-plan

What does it mean?
Azure Service Plan is displayed empty (Not Found), but cannot be deleted?

[image]

Comment: You should refresh your service plan list and see if the problem has resolved itself. I re-created this issue, and then had the empty service plan disappear around 20-30 minutes after deleting the web app within it. In any case, this is a portal behavior issue, not a programming issue. I'm voting to close it. You might want to consider contacting Azure support and reporting this.